# When will CSS 3 and HTML 5 become the official standards?

Tags: html, css, w3c, web-standards

I've been searching around trying to find an approximate date for the standardization of CSS 3 and HTML 5 to no avail. Does anyone know when W3C plans on updating the standards or have an estimation?

Comment: It's really not important, since W3C doesn't make the browsers.

Comment: Some browsers- such as chrome, safari, and firefox -are actually ahead of the standards, speculating about what might be added and implementing it in their own ways. They would only have to change the syntax. Internet Explorer, however, still has to catch up with standards that were created quite some time ago. The internet would be much better if the IE dev team moved on to create a totally unrelated product and microsoft installed a one-use version of internet explorer that you could only use to download browsers.

Comment: ie 9 is leaping ahead in terms of standards, it's still ie, but it's hardly a waste of time. Worth testing out the beta.  http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/

Comment: @generelhenry Thanks for the heads up! IE9 is (by my tests) the fastest browser available for  windows (at least for rendering that microsoft-created fish tank)

Comment: You do know that "Is it a standard" is mostly the wrong question. AJAX - the stuff we've all be using for 5 years - isn't a standard, in fact it just reached proposed recommendation status this August. There are only 3 official CSS full standards (out of the hundreds of CSS stuff that we use everyday)

Comment: When w3c makes it a standard, the syntax for browsers such as chrome, safari, and firefox will all be the same. Internet explorer, no matter how fast it now is, will not catch up to the times for quite a while. Too much time spent ignoring the standards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i believe the official line is that it will be done when its done. theres a tremendous amount of work still left to do on it.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't really expecting a definite answer, and you confirmed my suspicion that CSS3 and HTML5 are still pretty far from complete.

Comment: The same line as Blizzard and 3DRealms. This could be interpreted as good or bad...

Comment: its both good AND bad. it means that they arent doing a half-assed job (or one would hope they werent) but that its going to take a longer time.

Answer (score 3):

The [WhatWG FAQ page](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/FAQ#When_will_HTML5_be_finished.3F) has interesting information about this, for HTML5 at least:

> In the interests of full disclosure, the W3C's official line is that the HTML5 spec will be complete, with interoperable implementations, in late 2010. However, that same timetable gave a date for First Public Working Draft that was eight months premature, and the W3C, as of the predicted date for the third milestone, Candidate Recommendation, had still not come anywhere near reaching the second milestone, Last Call. You can make your own judgements regarding the W3C timetable's credibility.

And as to whether it matters when the standard is finalised:

> The real question is, when can you use new features?
>
> ...
> Different parts of the specification are at different maturity levels. Some sections are already relatively stable and there are implementations that are already quite close to completion, and those features can be used today (e.g. canvas). But other sections are still being actively worked on and changed regularly, or not even written yet.
>
> ...
> The point to all this is that you shouldn’t place too much weight on the status of the specification as a whole. You need to consider the stability and maturity level of each section individually.

Answer (score 2):

Even if they roll it out tomorrow, it's still going to take some time for browsers to be updated and then the users to adopt the new browsers... The way IE6 is still hanging on, it probably won't be to the user in this lifetime :)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone reading this post in 2014...

> *The plan is to release a stable HTML5 Recommendation by the end of 2014*

[source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5#Plan_2014)

Answer (score 0):

On 28 October 2014 `HTML5` became 
[W3C official standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/)